# configure the left and right mac 'command' keys differently?

Tags: macos, keyboard, command, configure

I'm wandering if I can set the right mac 'command' to act like the ctrl key, but keep the default functionality of the left 'command' key.
Thanks.

Comment: Probably not - I think they are connected to each other (electrically) on most keyboards.

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser.com (unless you want a programmatic way to do it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a really awesome application called Ukelele (free) that is, unfortunately, unable to distinguish between left and right command keys.  However, there is an even better application I recently found called "ControllerMate" that lets you do exactly what you want.  You can find it here: http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/

If you have questions about how to use it... well that's a totally different topic.  It took me literally 30 seconds to accomplish what you want though.

The only caveat is the free version has some limitations that are really annoying, so it may be worth the 15 bucks to register it.